# You have an error in your SQL syntax; about Mysql SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, sql-injection

I test a WAF.and I enter my SQL in Mysql console:

```
select * from test where id='-1' union select table_name,1,1 from/*/*/**/information_schema.tables limit 0,1;
```

the SQL syntax is correct,and show the table_name 
but if you enter the below sql syntax.

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=-1' union select table_name,1,1 from/*/*/**/information_schema.tables limit 0,1%23
```

in your brower ,you can see the below error.

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near **/information_schema.tables limit 0,1#
```

and this is same test environment version.The question is why Mysql conole can parsed the syntax,but browser not.

so,What's wrong?and Why the error only appear in brower but mysql console can handle it ?How can fix it

Comment: What are all those slashes and stars for? Are you trying to create a comment? Also, shouldn't UNION go between two select statements? Why are you trying to end the statement with a hash symbol?

Comment: Sorry,my sql console syntax is:select * from test where id='-1'union select table_name,1,1 from/*/*/**/information_schema.tables limit 0,1;                                       no hash,and  the  comment is work for bypass the WAF

Comment: A copy of your PHP code might be nice to decipher what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your union clause at the beginning of your SQL statement does not make sense as UNION should appear between two SELECT statements.

I am a bit confused with what your code is trying to do, but the opening /* and closing */ indicates a comment that is ignored by the SQL parser. Breaking this up, everything on the second line below will be ignored and treated as a comment

```
union select table_name,1,1 from
   /*/*/
**/information_schema.tables limit 0,1#
```

Therefore your third line with **/ does not make sense.

It is a bit unclear how you are testing this in your browser or if two different SQL parsers are involved. However, what your code is doing is closing a comment inside of a comment. In other words you have a partially nested comment.

From the [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html) documentation:

"Nested comments are not supported. (Under some conditions, nested comments might be permitted, but usually are not, and users should avoid them.)"

The MySQL 5.0 documentation simply says:

"Nested comments are not supported."

I am not sure if it is just the wording that has changed here or if the way comments are parsed has actually changed.

Comment: sorry,I miss the SELECT part .and  this is  same test environment version.The question is why Mysql conole can parsed the syntax,but browser not.